# Sort integer array into decreasing order of frequency

Tags: java, arrays, frequency

I need to take a string from a jTextFrame then sort it into order of occurence and then print it out. eg. babablackbike return: bbbbaaakkceil

```
    String word = (String)jTextField1.getText();
    String indexes = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int[] count = new int[indexes.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) 
    {
        int index = indexes.indexOf(word.charAt(i));

        if (index < 0)
            continue;

        count[index]++;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < count.length; j++) 
    {
        if (count[j] < 1)
            continue;

        char[] indiv = indexes.toCharArray();

        for (int p = 0; p < count[j];p++)
        {
            jTextArea1.append(""+indiv[j]);
            System.out.println(indiv[(j)] +"="+ count[j] + p);
        }     
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? What issues are you facing? BTw, did you consider using a `Map`?

Comment: Classmate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459792/string-sorted-in-descending-order?

Comment: Luckily, they will not be caught for copying :) They got a variety of options!

Answer (score 0):

I think that, the best solution it would be to create a HashMap like this

```
Map<Character, Integer> quantity = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
```

Then, you can do a loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
  char c = str.charAt(i);
  // increment value of c in quantity map
}
```

After that, you can sort it by value and easily print.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get counts of each character in your input:

```
final String in = "babablackbike";
final Map<Character, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
final List<Character> inList = new ArrayList<>();
for (final char c : in.toCharArray()) {
    Integer count = counts.get(c);
    if (count == null) {
        counts.put(c, 1);
    } else {
        counts.put(c, count + 1);
    }
    inList.add(c);
}
```

As Java is a bit peculiar with `char[]` versus `Character[]` - there is no way to sort primitives with a custom comparator due to generics not working with primitives - I also build a `List<Character>` at the same time.

Now we just need to sort the `List<Character>` using a custom `Comparator` and the information in the `Map counts`:

```
Collections.sort(inList, new Comparator<Character>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(final Character o1, final Character o2) {
        int c = counts.get(o1).compareTo(counts.get(o2));
        if (c != 0) {
            return -c;
        }
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
});
```

So first we sort by the count of the character in the input (reverse order) and then we sort by the characters themselves.

Now we simply need to build the `List` back into a `String`:

```
final StringBuilder outBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (final Character c : inList) {
    outBuilder.append(c);
}
System.out.println(outBuilder.toString());
```

Output:

```
bbbbaaakkceil
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the general algorithm:**

1. Map each character in the string to the number of times it appears in it.
2. Sort the map keys (characters) by decreasing order of their values (count).
3. Print each character according to the number of times it appears in the string.

---

**And here is a coding example:**

```
public void Print(String string)
{
    HashMap<Character,Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
    TreeMap<Character,Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<Character,Integer>(new ValueComparator(hashMap));
    for (Character key : string.toCharArray())
    {
        Integer value = hashMap.get(key);
        if (value == null)
            hashMap.put(key,1);
        else
            hashMap.put(key,value+1);
    }
    treeMap.putAll(hashMap);
    for (Character key : treeMap.keySet())
    {
        Integer value = hashMap.get(key);
        for (Integer i=0; i<value; i++)
            System.out.print(key);
    }
}

private class ValueComparator implements Comparator<Character>
{
    Map<Character,Integer> base;
    public ValueComparator(Map<Character,Integer> base)
    {
        this.base = base;
    }
    public int compare(Character a,Character b)
    {
        if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b))
            return -1;
        else
            return +1;
    }
}
```